# Slick slider изменить кол-во слайдов после инициализации

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, responsive

Как можно изменить количество отображаемых слайдов у `slick slider`, при изменении экрана. На текущей момент решением является - скрытие старого слайдера и инициализация нового. Можно ли обойтись только одним слайдером и менять количество отображаемых слайдов при изменении размеров экрана, т.е. уже после инициализации:
P.S. Переинициализировать заново не выходит

```js
$('.center').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) есть такое поле как `breakpoint`, с помощью чего вы можете поменять количество отображаемых картинок.

Пример из документации:

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```